# Get content with ampersand through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an editable table cell
`<td class="center" contenteditable="true" onblur="saveToDB(this, 'docTitle', '<?= $row->id; ?>')"><?= $row->docTitle ?></td>`

and here the function

```
function saveToDB(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#B2DDF2 url(../img/AjaxLoader.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>documents/inline_update",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.textContent+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
        });
    }
```

Whenever user enter data with an ampersand (Eg. Forms & Format), only Forms will be inserted into database.
I have tried `innerText` but still get the same result.

What are the options to achieve this without escape / encode ampersand?

Comment: What does your backend code look like? Also you will have to encode it somehow, unless you manually parse the raw POST body on the backend.

Comment: I recommend you posting JSON instead of passing parameter as querytsring, which is based on how you handle posted data on server side.

Comment: Even though the question is, _“to achieve this without escape / encode ampersand”_, that doesn’t make much sense - `encodeURIComponent`, as mentioned in the now deleted answer, _is_ the correct way to do this.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to use base64 to avoid this kind of troubles. 
    `atob()`
    `btoa()`

Comment: But because your server handle some chars in a strange way, it mean clearly that there is a XSS flaw; be careful. Don't trust user data's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just provide an object as data and jQuery will take care of proper serialization and escaping for you (it will use utility `$.param` internally which will apply escaping to data values):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    column: column,
    editval: editableObj.textContent,
    id: id,
  },
  success: function (data) { },
});
```

Comment: @ocanal It has nothing to do with JSON, and there is no need to decode anything on server. Data is sent as form-url-encoded, no JSON involved.

Comment: hımm yes you are right, no need decoding JSON, it's already in `$_POST`, but I think OP using `$_GET` to handle querystring parameter.

Comment: There are no query string parameters also. OP uses POST and form-url-encoded content type. It means that data is sent in key-value pairs separated by `&`. It looks like query string, but it's not.

Comment: Now i see, I thought that OP concatenating paremeters with url paremeters, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Thank you. Never thought of this.